# Angular interceptor: Send request only after the first came back

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor, subject

How can i implement fifo queue inside angular interceptor?

So if first request sent the second request will be executed only after the first get back.

I saw a lot of examples of RXJS queue(like subject, but i don't care if there is other approach), but i cant figure out how to combine it with the interceptor logic...

```
private queue = new Subject();

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { 

          this.queue...???

          return next.handle(request).pipe(

          );

    }
```

Comment: what do you want to do in this.queue....

Comment: I want the request will go one after another. And second request will not sent until the first back.

Comment: you mean all the request sent by angular?

Comment: Yes, thats is the interceptor

Comment: When you call next on interceptor means it passes the request to the next interceptor. It doesn't have the capability to put every Http request in a queue. I'll suggest you create a http service to handle this

Comment: What decides when the queue should be cleared?